# Symfony2 Doctrine Custom Repository Class [Semantical Error] line 0, col 102

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am getting this error  [Semantical Error] line 0, col 102 near 'pw WHERE pw.startdate': Error: 'pw' is already defined. This is what I have:

```
  public function findBystartdateAndenddate($startdate, $enddate)
{
   return $this
    ->createQueryBuilder('pw')
     ->select('pw')
     ->from ('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek','pw')
     ->where ('pw.startdate = :startdate and pw.enddate = :enddate')
    ->setParameter('startdate', $startdate)
    ->setParameter('enddate', $enddate)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();
```

Comment: `public function findBystartdateAndenddate($startdate, $enddate)` where using in Repository?

Comment: yeah it is a custom repository

Answer (score 1):

```
 ->from ('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')
```

This should Work

Answer (score 1):

```
->from ('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek')
```

if you want  try DQL :

```
$query =$this->_em->createQuery('select a, DATE_DIFF(startdate, enddate) from "" ');


public function getByDate(\Datetime $date)
{
    $from = new \DateTime($date->format("Y-m-d")." 00:00:00");
    $to   = new \DateTime($date->format("Y-m-d")." 23:59:59");

    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder("e");
    $qb
        ->andWhere('e.date BETWEEN :from AND :to')
        ->setParameter('from', $from )
        ->setParameter('to', $to)
    ;
    $result = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

    return $result;
}
```

Comment: ok thanks but i don't want a date difference. I want them to match.

Comment: it s okey you just want to compare 2 date i guess you need to convert date because date in database and date in php they dont have the same format .

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:
Your error is two time use `pw` in (`->createQueryBuilder('pw')` and `->from ('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek','pw')`)

```
public function findBystartdateAndenddate($startdate, $enddate)
{
   return $this
       ->createQueryBuilder('pw')
       ->select('pw')
       ->where ('pw.startdate = :startdate')
       ->andWhere('pw.enddate = :enddate')
       ->setParameter('startdate', $startdate)
       ->setParameter('enddate', $enddate)
       ->getQuery()
       ->getResult();
}
```

Also you can in `Controller` call criteria f.e:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('YourFooBundle:YourEntity')->findBy(array('startdate' => $startdate, 'enddate' => $enddate));
```

Comment: This was the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618502/using-count-in-doctrine-query-language.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove `->from ('comtwclagripayrollBundle:Payrollweek','pw')`. Because you can already create object using `->createQueryBuilder('pw')` for current repository

```
public function findBystartdateAndenddate($startdate, $enddate)
{
   return $this
     ->createQueryBuilder('pw')
     ->select('pw')
     ->where ('startdate = :startdate and enddate = :enddate')
     ->setParameter('startdate', $startdate)
     ->setParameter('enddate', $enddate)
     ->getQuery()
     ->getResult();
```